# Opengraph displaying as One to One - Without Object Title

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

In my facebook app i have given the necessary meta tags for the open graph url. When i publish a story using open graph, the story is published on the wall as `One to One - Without Object Title` mode. When i view it in open graph settings, `the One to One` mode is displayed correctly. I have added a screenshot for better understanding

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Answered the same question here [Facebook Open Graph Not Showing Object Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392373/facebook-open-graph-not-showing-object-title/18633330#18633330)

I have a workaround:

1. To your "school" object add a property "name" of type string.
2. Edit your story "visited school": In the **One to One without object
   title** change the story to "visited a {school.name} via Eduraft"
   from "visited a {school.title} via Eduraft"
3. Save the changes.
4. When creating the school object, then along with "title" provide
   same string to the property name. Publish the story.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
i got perfect solution try this:

- Change the story of the type "One to One - Without Object Title" as **"Object"** from "**Object.noun**".

For e.g: Story sentense would be as follow:

**"Tejas ran race with sample."**
Here race is my object.

- Keep the sentence of story of the type "One to One" as **Object.title** as it is.

For e.g: **"Tejas ran race.title with sample."**
Here race is my object.

Thanks,
Tejas