# Facebook Open Graph Not Showing Object Title

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm having conflicting reports for our users that people that share Object Graph objects to their wall, are sometimes showing the Object title and other times not. Specifically, every test I do on my own account shows the Object Title, but on their Mobile apps - it doesn't appear. I've tested the Open Graph debugger.So I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a length limit on the number of characters?
2. Does Facebook not show the whole Object.title on Mobile?
3. Does Facebook scrap the OG tags and if it can't find them or if it timeout do they not receive them?

Here is my sample OG url:

https://untappd.com/user/gregavola/checkin/35486976

Response from FB:
[image]

Post on my Wall:
[image]

What can I do here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround:

1. To your "beer object" add a property "name" of type string.
2. Edit your story "drank beer": In the **One to One without object title** change the story to " drank a **{beer.name}** via Untappd" from " drank a **{beer.title}** via Untappd"
3. Save the changes.
4. When creating the beer object, then along with "title" provide same string to the property name.
5. Publish the story.

Comment: Does this have to be within the "POST" command to create the new object, does this have to live on the actual web page we are linking to?

Comment: @GauravVashisth I have done all this - added og:name to my self-hosted object (equivalent of all the meta tags for OP's 'beer'); added the property name to my object type; and edited the one to one without obj title to include beer.name rather than beer.title. But on mobile, the appearance still looks exactly the same. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267103/ensuring-facebook-opengraph-posts-look-the-same-on-mobile-and-desktop

Comment: @GauravVashisth I tried the same thing but I am still publishing without the title. The Facebook debugger recognizes my property "name" on my object but then the story still publishes without object title.  Is there any other thing I need to do to force Facebook to publish the object title in the story summary?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026694/posting-to-open-graph-does-not-show-object-title-in-the-post#24907317) link. Its working fine for me. And I think this is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try clear cache here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
Also you can try set Facebook share link like:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com&p[title]=mytitle&p[summary]=mysummary