# Ensuring Facebook Opengraph posts look the same on mobile and desktop

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-opengraph

I have an app that makes posts to facebook via a self-hosted object using open graph.

On desktop, the post looks exactly as I want. Here is how it looks:
[image: Desktop Correct Post]

And here is how it looks on mobile (incorrect, seemingly ignoring my sentence construction in the app admin console as well as my OG meta tags in my self-hosted object:
[image: Bad mobile]

I am trying to find a way to make my mobile posts look more like this one, which seems to have its open graph meta tags honored on mobile as well as desktop (mobile shown here):
[image: good mobile]

Can anyone let me know if I am making a crucial mistake? I can also share the meta tags in the self-hosted object if that will help get to the bottom of this!