# Object title not being used by Facebook in Open Graph share

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the new Facebook API (v4.4) with `ShareOpenGraphObject`, `ShareOpenGraphAction` and `ShareOpenGraphContent`. I can't get the title to have an effect on the share description. I was assuming that if I added `og:title` then it would use the "One to One" sentence so.

> Will completed {level.title} on WordBuzz.

but it's using the "One to One - Without Object Title" sentence instead

> Will completed a level on WordBuzz.

The title is clearly being sent, as it's being shown in the title above the description (screenshot at the bottom), but I don't understand why it's not being used in the above sentence.

How do I get Facebook to display the level title? I'm aware there are hacks to work around this on StackOverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392373/facebook-open-graph-not-showing-object-title) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026694/posting-to-open-graph-does-not-show-object-title-in-the-post#24907317). But I'm assuming it's possible to get this working as it should!

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "scribble-wordbuzz:level")
            .putString("og:title", "Level 14")
            .putString("og:level.title", "Level 14")  // test
            .putString("scribble-wordbuzz:title", "Level 14")  // test
            .putString("scribble-wordbuzz:level.title", "Level 14")  // test
            .putString("og:description", "Here's the level description")
            .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("scribble-wordbuzz:complete")
            .putObject("level", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("level")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(content);
```

[image]

Comment: If you think the API is broken, please create a bug report with Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs