# Cannot publish Facebook story with title

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, title

I'm having trouble with facebook open graph story. All I want is just to publish a story with object title. I tried to use open graph object debugger, I can clearly see that og:title is defined but there is no title in feeds I published.

I also tried to use the workaround the link provided without luck

[Facebook Open Graph Not Showing Object Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392373/facebook-open-graph-not-showing-object-title/18633330#18633330)

any ideas? Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I made it work doing this:

Go to the Facebook Graph API Stories panel.

Keep the sentence of story of the type "One to One" as Object.title as it is.
example: "Agus shared {item.title}", where "item" is my object.

Change the story of the type "One to One - Without Object Title" from "Object.noun" to "Object".
example: "Agus shared {item.noun}" --> "Agus shared {item}", where "item" is my object.